# Get Objects in Array which are less then, Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

as written i have in my DB a property called weeks.
This is an Array which contains Objects.
I want to retrieve all objects which are gt / lt.

Im looking for all objects with the property qdate ->lt 20210226

The field in MongoDB is called weeks, it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "00"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250600",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "15"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250615",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "30"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250630",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "45"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102260645",
        "qdate": 20210226,
        "booked": false
    },
]
```

I tried this query :

```
 const company = await Company.find({
    email: 'testme@gmail.com',
    weeks: { $elemMatch: { qdate: { $lt: ['qdate', 20210225] } } }
  })
```

But then i receive an empty array.
Also i tried this :

```
 const company = await Company.find({
    email: 'testme@gmail.com',
    weeks: { $elemMatch: { qdate: { $lt: ['qdate', 20210225] } } }
  })

///

const company = await Company.find({
    email: 'buzzer79@gmail.com',
    'weeks.$.qdate': { $lt: 20210225 },
  });
```

Also i get [];

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, all your `qdate` values are equal or greater than `20210225`. So why would you expect to see anything other than an empty array when you run `$lt: ['qdate', 20210225]`? Have you tried `$lte`?

Comment: Actually the last element is "qdate": 20210226 so therefore i could expect to see the values with "qdate": 20210225

Comment: Sure but `20210226` is GREATER than `20210225`. Is it not? Stands to reason that to see it, you would have to run `$gt: ['qdate', 20210225]`. Am I wrong?

Comment: So imagine i have in total objects which represents 3 weeks, around 200. Each Object is a time window where someone can book an appointment.

I render it in React week wise, so now after 1 day passed i want to set it to false and it shouldnt appear anymore on the calendar. After 1 week passed so 6 days, i want to wipe the days and push 1 week to the array. 

Therefore i want select the lower range and wipe it.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found out, that running a query with find always will return one element. To get all occurrences of my weeks array with the value of 20210225 its needed to let it run via the aggregate pipeline.

So at the end my query looks like this:

```
const company = await Company.aggregate([
    { $match: { email: 'test@gmail.com' } },
    { $unwind: '$weeks' },
    { $match: { 'weeks.qdate': 20210225 } },
    {
      $project: {
        weeks: 1,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

And this returns this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "602b275d26f77d1294c4e998",
        "weeks": {
            "time": [
                "06",
                "00"
            ],
            "active": false,
            "reason": "",
            "bookTime": "202102250600",
            "qdate": 20210225,
            "booked": false
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "602b275d26f77d1294c4e998",
        "weeks": {
            "time": [
                "06",
                "15"
            ],
            "active": false,
            "reason": "",
            "bookTime": "202102250615",
            "qdate": 20210225,
            "booked": false
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "602b275d26f77d1294c4e998",
        "weeks": {
            "time": [
                "06",
                "30"
            ],
            "active": false,
            "reason": "",
            "bookTime": "202102250630",
            "qdate": 20210225,
            "booked": false
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "602b275d26f77d1294c4e998",
        "weeks": {
            "time": [
                "06",
                "45"
            ],
            "active": false,
            "reason": "",
            "bookTime": "202102250645",
            "qdate": 20210225,
            "booked": false
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "602b275d26f77d1294c4e998",
        "weeks": {
            "time": [
                "07",
                "00"
            ],
            "active": false,
            "reason": "",
            "bookTime": "202102250700",
            "qdate": 20210225,
            "booked": false
        }
    },
];

case closed
```